# How do i use onclick() method properly when passing some variable arguements i.e the arguements in this case is an ID of a Mongoose Object Document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

So I'm dynamically appending rows to a table on front-end, based on the array I get from a node.js API I wrote. The array indicates students. For each row I append and display **Name**, **Class**, **Roll_No** and a dynamic button whose color changes depending on the value I get from that specific student. Now for that button I use the following tag:

```
$('#users').append("<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td>" + val.first_name + " " + val.last_name + "</td><td>" + val.roll_no + "</td><td>" + val.class + "</td><td><button id='tempButton' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='add_remove_student(" + val._id + ", " + val.is_linked + ")'>DELETE</button></td></tr>");
```

`val` indicates the current element of the students array, which is a mongoose object. Now I get an error whenever I click the appended button and the `add_remove_student()` method is not called. The error says:

> uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

`val._id` is a Mongoose ID of that particular Mongoose object and `val.is_linked` is a boolean value.

The `onclick()` in the button tag worked before I switched to node.js

I've scratched my head so many times as to what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've wrecked my brain for 24 hrs to solve this and after understanding how escape quotes characters work i've finally solved it with the following code:

```
$('#users').append(`<tr><td>` + (i + 1) + `</td><td>` + val.first_name + ` ` + val.last_name + `</td><td>` + val.roll_no + `</td><td>` + val.class + `</td><td><button id="tempButton" class="btn btn-danger" onclick='add_remove_student(\"` + val._id + `\",\"` + val.is_linked + `\")'>DELETE</button></td><tr>`);
```

Thank You ^^

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: *don't use `onclick`*, or any other of the `onX` inline event attributes. They are outdated, lead to spaghetti code and don't follow the separation of concerns principle.

A much better way to achieve this would be to just add the relevant meta data to the element as `data` attributes. Then, using a single delegated event handler, you can read that metadata from the element which was clicked. Try this:

```js
let i = 0;
let val = {
  _id: "5e4780d3cfbe57182499506a",
  role: ["STUDENT"],
  is_active: true,
  linked_students: [],
  first_name: "test_fname",
  last_name: "test_lname",
  email: "t1@t.com",
  roll_no: "537",
  class: 7,
  description: "im a test user mate!",
  created_at: "2020-02-15T05:25:39.077Z",
  updatedAt: "2020-02-15T05:25:39.077Z",
  v: 0,
  is_linked: true
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#users').append(`<tr><td>${(++i)}</td><td>${val.first_name} ${val.last_name}</td><td>${val.roll_no}</td><td>${val.class}</td><td><button class="delete btn btn-danger" data-id="${val._id}" data-linked="${val.is_linked}">DELETE</button></td></tr>`);
});

$('#users').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  let $btn = $(this);
  let id = $btn.data('id');
  let isLinked = $btn.data('linked');
  console.log(id, isLinked);

  // do something with the above data...

  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Append</button>
<table id="users"></table>
```

As a side note, don't use `id` attributes in content which will be dynamically repeated. `id` need to be unique in the DOM. Use `class` attributes instead.

If, for whatever reason, you absolutely *had* to use an inline event attribute you need to fix your quotes so that they match, and you also need to escape the quotes you use in the `onclick` value so they don't interfere with the outer string:

```js
$('#users').append('<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + val.first_name + ' ' + val.last_name + '</td><td>' + val.roll_no + '</td><td>' + val.class + '</td><td><button id="tempButton" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="add_remove_student(\"' + val._id + '\", \"' + val.is_linked + '\")">DELETE</button></td></tr>');
```

Comment: First of All, Thank You For the Help! Secondly, I'm kind of in a case that i absolutely have to use Inline tag tho i'll keep you'r advice in mind for the future. Thirdly, I use the Code u mentioned in the end that uses correct quotes but it still gives another error saying: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Could you give an example of what the `val` object looks like that causes that error

Comment: val objects look something like this and i get an array of em from api response:

_id: "5e4780d3cfbe57182499506a"
role: ["STUDENT"]
is_active: true
linked_students: []
first_name: "test_fname"
last_name: "test_lname"
email: "t1@t.com"
roll_no: "537"
class: 7
description: "im a test user mate!"
created_at: "2020-02-15T05:25:39.077Z"
updatedAt: "2020-02-15T05:25:39.077Z"
__v: 0
is_linked: true
__proto__: Object

Comment: apologies for the mess but well its a mongoose object XD

Comment: Thanks for updating, however it still appears to work - as you can see from the updated answer. I'd suggest you check the actual HTML output and make sure it's entirely valid. It's possible there's some quotes in the values which are causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of mixing of quotes please re verify the quotes on the function calling in jquery. Plus please made an id of the element dynamic.

Comment: Thank You for the Advice!, I'll be sure to keep Id's unique in future